# flutter generate doesn't annotated classes for test directory

Tags: dependency-injection, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

So I've tried generate classes DI classes for the [inject.dart](https://github.com/google/inject.dart) using `flutter generate`

It seems to generate classes under lib/* but not for test/*. It does not throw any error as such. Here are my relevant flutter classes.

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: gc_client
description: A gc

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  json_annotation: ^2.0.0
  rxdart: ^0.22.0
  dio: ^2.1.3
  inject:
    path: ./inject.dart/package/inject

builders:
  json_serializable: ^2.0.0
  inject_generator:
    path: ./inject.dart/package/inject_generator

dev_dependencies:
  test: 1.6.1
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  mockito: ^4.0.0


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  fonts:
  - family: Raleway
    fonts:
    - asset: assets/fonts/raleway_regular.ttf
    - asset: assets/fonts/raleway_medium.ttf
      weight: 700

  assets:
  - assets/
```

**Component classes**

[image: The two injection components]

Am I missing something? Let me know if you need more info. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the build runner.

Here's a relevant fix for the same

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33266